# Computing the constant in BSD conjecture

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. An old formulation of the BSD conjecture is that
$$\prod_{p \leq X}\frac{|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|}{p} \sim C(\log X)^r$$
where $r$ is the rank of $E/\mathbb{Q}$, and $C$ is some constant depending only on $E$.

My question is: given $E$, is it possible to estimate $C$ quickly/ without just essentially computing $r$ first?

Comment: Most authors write $C_E(\log(x))^{r_E}$. This is the "OBSD" (original Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can access $C$ without knowing $r$ first, and that asymptotic estimate is going to approached quite slowly and erratically, assuming it is true in the first place.

And the truth of that asymptotic estimate (for some $C$ and $r$) lies much deeper than the usual BSD, since it implies GRH for the $L$-function of $E$.  That fact, and a formula for $C$ in terms of the first nonvanishing term in the $L$-function for $E$ at $s = 1$, is due to Goldfeld. See Theorem 1.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/articles/eulerprod.pdf), which has a generalization to other partial Euler products.

By the way, at primes $p$ of bad reduction, replace $|E(\mathbf F_p)|$ with the number of nonsingular $\mathbf F_p$-rational points.